# Google Document List Java API - Updated-min

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

It seems that using the DocumentQuery where using updatedMin seems to to not be working correctly.  This query does find new files and folders that were created since the "when" but fails to return files that were modified, moved, trashed, or anything else since the when.

```
DocumentQuery myQuery = new DocumentQuery(new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/"));
myQuery.setUpdatedMin(when);
DocumentListFeed entries = getDocsService().getFeed(myQuery, DocumentListFeed.class);
```

I realize that the API might be changing with the upcoming Google Drive, has something changed in the interim?

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve documents that have been edited since a specific date, use the [`edited-min`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#parameter_reference_for_resources_collection_uri) query parameter.

From a `DocumentQuery` instance, you can use the [`addCustomParameter`](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/Query.html#addCustomParameter%28com.google.gdata.client.Query.CustomParameter%29) to set such a value.

```
query.addCustomParameter(
    new Query.CustomParameter("edited-min", "<DATE_IN_RFC_3339_FORMAT>");
```